# How to use hyperledger caliper with quorum blockchain ? i didn't undrestand how it works and i looked for a tutoriol but i didn't found, i use linux

Tags: blockchain, solidity, benchmarking, quorum, hyperledger-caliper

I am trying to figure out how to use Caliper to do benchmark testing in quorum blockchain network and I am getting nowhere.
I try to follow this tutoriel https://nima-afraz.medium.com/hyperledger-caliper-explained-and-installation-guide-ubuntu-c38dc16d3dcf  that used caliper with fabric but i got stuck, i installed docker version 23.0.4 and docker-compose version 1.29.2, i installed caliper v 0.3.2 and i installed caliper-quorum@0.3.1, but i don't know how to use them and what are the steps to run a benchmark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger caliper has never supported Quorum. The package `caliper-quorum` appears to be someones personal project for a caliper connector. Caliper doesn't support the concept of dynamic connectors so you can't just install caliper and a supposed caliper connector and expect it to work, it would require changes to caliper itself to know of the existance of the connector. Whoever wrote that plugin probably made their own changes to caliper as well to make it work.

I would say that unless you can raise an issue with the author of the caliper-quorum plugin to find out how they made it work along with example benchmarks and configuration files required, then your only other choice is to look at the code for caliper and the code for the caliper-quorum module and work out yourself how to make it work. Normally I would recommend using the latest version of caliper but caliper 0.4 introduced a new way to load the connectors so it would require a lot of re-engineering of the npm module you found to work with the new architecture. So you probably would have to look at the caliper 0.3 code base (which is now very old and not supported). Surfice to say there is no easy path here for you.

Comment: I'm back again and still stuck on this issue. I installed the Quorum adaptor for Caliper, from here :"https://libraries.io/npm/@salikzquidz%2Fcaliper-quorum",  but I can't figure out how to run it and connect it with Caliper. After preparing the configuration and running the command 'cd: caliper launch master --caliper-benchconfig benchconfig.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networkconfig.json', I keep getting the error message: 'Error: Module "quorum" could not be loaded: Error: Cannot find module 'quorum''. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry it just won't work without making code changes to caliper itself. You will have to figure out how to change caliper to work with that module and get caliper to explicitly load it. As I said this is not a trivial exercise and you will need to be very familiar with both the caliper code base and the code that makes up the Quorum adaptor

Comment: ok i will try again.. thanks for answering me back